# Installing mailman3 on Debian bookworm with external mail postfix server

Tags: debian, postfix, mailman

I would like to install mailman3 on my debian box (bookworm), but use an already existing postfix mail server on another host (can that be done?).

I have the following settings in the `mailman.cfg` file in `/etc/mailman3`

```
[mta]
# The class defining the interface to the incoming mail transport agent.
#incoming: mailman.mta.exim4.LMTP
incoming: mailman.mta.postfix.LMTP

# The callable implementing delivery to the outgoing mail transport agent.
# This must accept three arguments, the mailing list, the message, and the
# message metadata dictionary.
outgoing: mailman.mta.deliver.deliver

# How to connect to the outgoing MTA.  If smtp_user and smtp_pass is given,
# then Mailman will attempt to log into the MTA when making a new connection.
smtp_host: localhost
smtp_port: 25
smtp_user:
smtp_pass:

# Where the LMTP server listens for connections.  Use 127.0.0.1 instead of
# localhost for Postfix integration, because Postfix only consults DNS
# (e.g. not /etc/hosts).
lmtp_host: 127.0.0.1
lmtp_port: 8024
```

I have SSH tunnels in place which make port 25 on the remote mail server available from my mailman server and port 8024 on my mailman server available on port 8024 on the remote mail server (if that's what's do be done - for the 2nd part, the port 8024, I am not fully sure if my understanding is correct).

For some reasons, when starting mailman3, it tries to execute `postmap` which is installed on the mail server, but not on the mailman server. I guess, that this occurs because of the config file settings for `incoming:` and `outgoing:`.

How can I change my configuration to get this setup working?
Or (if this is not possible): How should I configure my system to have a new system running `mailman3` connect to an already existing server running `postfix`.

(What I probably should mention: The mailing lists should be for the mail domain which the existing `postfix` mail server is responsible for.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have updated your `mailman.cfg` configuration and you have made SMTP and LMTP ports available on both servers, but you've missed the part "Transport maps" from the [docs](https://docs.mailman3.org/projects/mailman/en/latest/src/mailman/docs/mta.html#transport-maps), that requires three parameters to be set in Postfix: transport_maps, local_recipient_maps, and relay_domains.

Those three parameters must point to files `postfix_domains` and `postfix_lmtp`, which Mailman generates and keeps up to date, based on the domains and lists added to it. It does it via the `postmap` utility, that you mentioned.

Thus you have to add three parameters to your Postfix configuration, share a folder `<var_dir>/data` in the Mailman server with the Postfix server, and provide Mailman with the `postmap` utility to make this configuration work.

There might be also some changes needed to integrate the solution with your existing Postfix configuration.